# JSF validation messages

Tags: jsf-2

I am validating the input fields at the time of validating i am using regex and min length and max length,

```
<h:inputText id="txtInput" 
                    value="#{bean.name}"
                    validatorMessage="Please enter valid name"
                    maxlength="40" label="Name"> 
                <f:validateLength minimum="2" maximum="40" />   
                <f:validateRegex pattern="[- 'a-zA-Z]*"/>
            </h:inputText>
```

In my validation.properties:

javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM=Please enter a minimum of {0} alphabetic characters 
your {1}
Here i am facing problem in validation messages that showing it is always displaying "Please enter valid name" it is not showing javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `validatorMessage="Please enter valid name"` from your `inputText`

and add (modified)

```
javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator.NOT_MATCHED = {1}: Validation Error: Value not according to pattern ''{0}''
```

to your `validation.properties`

that's way your both validations will be covered by custom messages...

B.T.W , [here a complete Reference to all available message that you can override in JSF 2.0.x](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/core/branches/2.0.x/api/src/main/resources/javax/faces/Messages.properties)

Comment: Hi Daniel,Thank's for your response if i remove that then i there are some more validation's in my project i.e Please enter only alpha-numeric characters for description or Please enter only alphabetic characters for name. my validation messages are diffenrent for different regex validation if i add RegexValidator.NOT_MATCHED = {1}: Validation Error: Value not according to pattern ''{0}' then i will get only this message for all regex validation

Comment: you were talking about this specific <h:inputText id="txtInput"... if you add the javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator.NOT_MATCHED to validation.properties and remove the validatorMessage from this specific <h:inputText id="txtInput"  you will receive only two types of validation error msgs 1) ....MINIMUM 2) ... NOT_MATCHED and you wont receive the validatorMessage="Please enter valid name" , am I wrong?