# Validation for checking the field value before submitting the page to the server

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have developed an JSF and richfaces based application, Here I want to know about a nice way to throw the warning to the user if described field (Rich:inplaceInput) is empty

I have created rich:extendedDataTable in which one of the column is this...

```
<rich:column width="120" id="col15" label="yardNo">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Yard Number"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <rich:inplaceInput value="#{r.runSlNo}" defaultLabel="Assign Manual Number" 
                           inputWidth="90" showControls="true"/>
</rich:column>
```

and i have created a rich:contextMenu for displaying menu like this...[image]

One commandbutton is also there for submitting the page.
I have two problems over here regarding rich:inplaceInput.
first,
I just dont want to allow the user to submit the page if the rich:InplaceInput value field is empty, rather throw an warning to fill it.
I know how to throw the error or warning before submitting the page.
Second, how can i avoid displaying contextMenu over rich:InplaceInput value but let it display at other 4 columns....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add required="true" to `inplaceInput` that way you wont submit the form... and you add `h:messages` bellow the table to display the error of required field or try adding `h:message` with for="id_of_the_rich:inplaceInput" and locate the `h:message` bellow the `<rich:inplaceInput`

Comment: first, I have already tried it...and second, I dont want to display the warning on the view page, but on a separate window... so I have used processvalidators....hope u will be aware of that

Comment: Sorry dear, when i tried earlier then it didnt worked but after u told me I tried again required=true      and u know what   Its Working

Comment: thanks buddy, just tell me to set a customized message to user.
currently it is throwing **j_id116:tblItems:0:j_id161: Validation Error: Value is required.**
but i want **"please assign Yard Number"**

Comment: for start, try set label="some meaningful name" on the <rich:inplaceInput or place value in here validatorMessage="some tex"

Comment: is there any sort method of displaying custom message 
I knows that properties and bundle method....

Comment: for more advanced way , read this http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/customize-validation-error-message-in-jsf-2-0/ and play with this entry javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED =

Comment: here an answer to validation related answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10071183/617373 with ref to complete messages list..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10635/discussion-between-abhinav-and-daniel)

Comment: but anyway do u know any way to hide the menu only for rich:inplaceInput value area.
for others it should display the menuitem like clicking on the other feild of the row

Comment: sorry , nope , (not a richfaces pro) but i think you can get the idea/inspiration from here https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ExtendedDataTableContextMenuWithDynamicDisabledMenuItemFeature

Comment: No man no inspiration as i want to bind a particular column for not displaying the contextMenu